# Unity and gnome-panel fighting over global bar 12.04

Tags: unity, panel, gnome-panel, titlebar

Like so many others I wish there was a way to [stop a window's title bar from merging with the global bar](https://askubuntu.com/q/59539/232778) at the top of the screen.  Today I installed gnome-panel to get the handy gnome-desktop-item-edit app because I wanted to add some scripts to the Unity launcher and I'm very happy to have the old familiar Applications and Places menus back.  I noticed that when my mouse travels between the global bar and the focused window, it toggles the global bar between the title of the window and gnome-panel.  Very annoying.  I already did `sudo apt-get autoremove appmenu-gtk appmenu-gtk3 appmenu-qt` to get the `File Edit` etc. menus out of the global bar and back into the window, as suggested [here](http://lifehacker.com/5887462/how-to-disable-ubuntus-annoying-global-menu-bar).  I'd like to make gnome-panel be always there.  I've get a relatively good idea of the title of the window that I'm in, after all, and I don't need it hiding gnome-panel.  Any way to fix this?  Or is it a "use a new desktop environment" scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with Gnome Classic and launching `gnome-panel` and `unity-2d-shell` as startup applications.  It might be perfect.  For me anyways... I get applications and places menus back on the top bar, windows key -> dash home, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run, and the unity launcher bar.  All of my favorite features from both environments and none of what I didn't like.